# Why did my disk suddenly stop working?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, external-hard-drive

I have a hdd and I am using it for about 3 months, I always used it in Ubuntu and everything was great until yesterday I put it on a windows laptop, the windows laptop could not read it and now I put it on my Ubuntu and it does not read it either, what happened ?

i used this command in ubuntu:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

and this is the result: but it does not worked

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
```

I want to use it again on my ubuntu, and sometimes in windows

Comment: Boot with a bootable USB Key and see if the drive is working. It may have failed.

Comment: @John the operating system is fine, what is wrong is my external hard drive

Comment: Try reading the drive from an external boot just to see. External drives are only a tad more reliable than USB keys so it has more than likely failed.

Comment: @John i can not read from a mac laptop as well

Comment: @John how can i solve this wrong, i have a lot information there, please help me

Comment: You need to take the disk to a local  recovery agency and get a quote for recovering data (if they can) .